# How can I get a mongoDB connection string for a site hosted on meteor.com?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a site hosted on meteor.com here: http://justicetodo.meteor.com/
I am trying to connect my mongoDB to this admin/visualization service here: https://www.humongous.io/
The website is asking for a connection string and listing the following as examples:

```
mongodb://user:password@domain:port/dbname

Standalone / no user

mongodb://8.8.8.8:27017/admin

Standalone with user

mongodb://sysop:moon@8.8.8.8:27017/admin

Replica sets / no user

mongodb://db1.example.net,db2.example.net:2500/admin
```

Comment: There is no real answer to this as they randomise and change the passwords every 60 seconds (I think...) You will get a very short time span live connection to your meteor hosted server. But still, `meteor mongo --url yoursite.meteor.com` does provide you with a temporary username and password.

Comment: Reformated the layout of the question to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't

```
meteor mongo --url yoursite.meteor.com
```

works?

Reference: http://meteorpedia.com/read/Mongo